# Why does this loop in Google Spreadsheet runs only once

Tags: loops, google-apps-script

I got a working VBA verion of code that I need to adapt and make it compatible on googlescript editor in spreadsheets

Looping seems so easy but as soon as I add steps below (for) 
the code runs only once with whatever value I have set the initial value of r in for. in this example only row 3 is populated.

```
    function myTESTFunction() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ActiveSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var rangeData = ActiveSheet.getDataRange();
var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
var searchRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(2,2, lastRow-1, lastColumn-1);
var TESTSHEET = ss.getSheetByName("TEST2");
Logger.clear()



  for ( r = 3;r<20;r++)  {

  row = r
  Logger.log(row)
  var DEBUTR = TESTSHEET.getRange(row,1);
  var INVR = TESTSHEET.getRange(row,2);
  var VENDUR = TESTSHEET.getRange(row,3);
  var COMMR = TESTSHEET.getRange(row,4);
  var TOTALR = TESTSHEET.getRange(row,5);
  TOTAL = TOTALR.setValue(INVR.getValue() + COMMR.getValue());

  return TOTAL;

  }


}
```

All I am trying to do is to add column 2 and 4 in column 5(only calculate numbers) all the way down to last row of data

then my next step after having a working Loop is to repeat this code for 40 times
by which i mean to use the same code in an additional loop that will then increment 4 columns to the right 40 times.

This is a simple ledger of inventory

the ranges are
(DEBUTR initial start of inventory--)
(INVR  current inventory to be entered by the user once a week--)
(VENDUR not coded yet but it would show the sold amount last total-current Inv--)
(COMMR  an order placed for re garnishing the stocks--)
(TOTALR what the total will be when calculating INVR  + COMMR--)

Comment: That loop only executes once because you force the method to exit with `return TOTAL;`, which is inside your loop. Your typo is placing the `for-loop`'s closing `}` after the return statement, instead of before it. **If you allow Apps Script to automatically indent your code, these typos are easy to spot.** Furthermore - the `Range#setValue()` method does not have a return value, so your `TOTAL` can only be `undefined`. You need to review batch methods as well, since you can avoid the very slow use of the Spreadsheet interface within your loop, and use only javascript arrays.